# Integrating Paystack Create Invoice Module using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, php-curl

I want to integrate "Create Invoice" Modules on Paystack into my website. This is because I want customers to be able to make their choices and pay for the item later rather than pay for it immediately and I saw the Create Invoice module on paystack but I cant seem to get it working.

Below is my code;

```
function sendPaystackInvoice() {

  var checkInv = PaystackPop.setup({
        key: 'key', //put your public key here

        description: "This is Your Invoice",
        line_items: [
            {
              name: document.getElementById("userOption").value,
              amount: document.getElementById("res").value * 100
            },
        ],
        customer: document.getElementById("emailA").value,
        due_date: "2019-30-10"
},
      callback: function (response) {

          $.post("createInv.php", {reference:response.reference}, function(status){
              if(status == "success")
                  //successful transaction
                  alert('Sales Invoice Sent');
              else
                  //transaction failed
                  alert(response);
          });
      }),
      onClose: function () {
          //when the user close the payment modal
          alert('Transaction cancelled');
      }
  });
  checkInv.openIframe();//open the paystack's payment modal
}
```

I successfully integrated the Initialize transaction and it works very well but I need help getting this done.

Below is the createInv.php file;

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/paymentrequest",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n\t\"description\": \"a test invoice\",\n\t\"line_items\": [\n\t\t{\"name\": \"item 1\", \"amount\": 20000},\n\t\t{\"name\": \"item 2\", \"amount\": 20000}\n\t],\n\t\"tax\": [\n\t\t{\"name\": \"VAT\", \"amount\": 2000}\n\t],\n\t\"customer\": \"CUS_je02lbimlqixzax\",\n\t\"due_date\": \"2017-05-08\"\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer SECRET_KEY",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: what actually is the problem?

Comment: Using the API reference i got from https://developers.paystack.co/v2.0/reference#create-invoice which i have tried, the code seems not to work. i know i am not doing something right which is why i needed help or someone pointing me to helpful directions...

Comment: We'll need some more specific details about the problem and the desired outcome. "Not working" isn't an error message or a description of your issue

Comment: P.s. the code above appears to be JavaScript, not PHP. Is there some relevant PHP somewhere? If not, please tag the question more appropriately

Comment: Okay.. I am trying to integrate the "Create Invoice (https://developers.paystack.co/v2.0/reference#create-invoice)" Module on Paystack into my website. I want a situation whereby a customer can make an order and Paystack automatically "Create an Invoice" so that the customer can make payment later. The Customer will get an email containing the payment link for the transaction.

Comment: The Code above is the Javascript function i am using but once i click the button nothing seems to happen. I need help or a pointer on what i can do to get this working

Comment: "nothing seems to happen". We will need more information than that. What debugging have you done? Do you understand how to use the Developer Tools in your browser to debug the JavaScript, look for errors, monitor the AJAX calls etc? That's the first place you need to start looking if you are having issues trying to get JavaScript code to work. We can't guess what the exact issue is, you need to at least work out roughly where the code fails, and report any errors or unusual output.

Comment: P.S. a secondary note...in the PHP part, in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` I _really_ wouldn't create JSON by hand like that. It's hard to read and prone to errors. And you don't need all those newline characters and tab either...the server isn't interested in the layout, only the data. Instead of making a raw string like that, create a PHP array and then use json_encode() to output it as a valid JSON string. Much more reliable and easier to debug and validate. Execute this demo to see what I mean: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bojm

Comment: ...note cont'd: Hopefully you can see that's much more reliable and the output is better too. Even though I hard-coded the data for that demo, it should be clear that this technique is useful in general for transforming data from other sources (e.g. a database perhaps) into JSON for transmission.